# Custom rounded background

Tags: android, android-studio, background, android-customview

Коллеги, добрый день. К сожалению я не очень разбираюсь в кастомных вьюхах, поэтому хочу спросить следующее:
Как можно реализовать BottomSheet примерно следующего вида(attach)?
Сам BottomSheet сделать не проблема - проблема сделать для него такой закруглённый задний фон. Пробовал через shape, но ничего хорошего не получилось.[image: закруглённый задний фон]

Comment: можно через VectorDrawable

Comment: нашел отличное решение в другом топике на стаке
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002541/how-to-set-relative-background-color-like-half-circle

Comment: там где используются dp не может быть отличным решением - будет все съезжать на разных экранах и ориентациях.

Comment: Всегда можно dimens разнести под разные экраны

Answer (score 1):

Создайте пользовательский rounded_dialog.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:topRightRadius="16dp"/>

</shape>
```

Затем переопределите bottomSheetDialogTheme на styles.xml используя bottomSheetDialogTheme в качестве фона:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">       
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
    parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle"
    parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_dialog</item>
</style>
```

короче нужно задавать background через style!

Comment: А что из этого даст такое специфическое закругление? 
Дизайнеры не стали париться по этому поводу и сделали его огромным кругом 1100х1100, кусочек которого как раз помещается на экран.
   
<corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:topRightRadius="16dp"/>
   в этом случае не поможет - это закруглит чуть с боков, но не даст такой округлости по всему верху

Comment: Ну так меняйте 16dp на 500dp в чем проблема?